# Traverse an array of pairs

Tags: go, graph

I am trying to understand golang better with some simple graphing. I was trying this out for a class and I can not really figure it out. The thing is I know that the solution is very simple. I am trying to get it to print off each individual path by reading the edges.

I have played with code quite a bit and this is really the simplest form I can get it.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Graph struct {
    Edges map[string][]string
}

// NewGraph: Create graph with n nodes.
func NewGraph() *Graph {
    return &Graph{
        Edges: make(map[string][]string),
    }
}

// AddEdge: Add an edge from u to v.
func (g *Graph) AddEdge(u, v string) {
    g.Edges[u] = append(g.Edges[u], v)

}


func (g *Graph) Walk(u string) {
    for _, v := range g.Edges[u] {
            fmt.Printf("%s -> %s", u, v)
        g.Walk(v)
    }
}

func (g *Graph) adjacentEdgesExample() {
    fmt.Println("Printing all edges in graph.")
    for u, adjacent := range g.Edges { // Nodes are labelled 0 to N-1.
        for _, v := range adjacent {
            // Edge exists from u to v.
            fmt.Printf("Edge: %s -> %s\n", u, v)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    g := NewGraph()
    g.AddEdge("A", "B")
    g.AddEdge("A", "D")
    g.AddEdge("D", "E")
    g.AddEdge("B", "C")
    g.adjacentEdgesExample()
    fmt.Println(g.Edges)
    g.Walk("A")

}
```

Example is at:

https://goplay.space/#Ro1puZYgu5X

It results in the output of:

```
Printing all edges in graph.
Edge: B -> C
Edge: A -> B
Edge: A -> D
Edge: D -> E
map[A:[B D] B:[C] D:[E]]
A -> BB -> CA -> DD -> E%
```

I would like to see the Walk method do something like this:

```
A -> B -> C
A -> D -> E
```

Comment: Does this helps: https://goplay.space/#HT2ejwQsU2L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality there are a lot of things that could be changed in the code (check out David Narepaks code [here](http://goplay.space/#HT2ejwQsU2L)). However, a quick fix to the `Walk` function checking if it is the base edge fixes the formatting issue. It should now be called from the `main` with `g.Walk("A", true)`.

```
func (g *Graph) Walk(u string, f bool) {
    for _, v := range g.Edges[u] {
        if f == true {
            fmt.Printf("\n%s -> %s", u, v)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf(" -> %s", v)
        }
        g.Walk(v, false)
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Acually, you could just check for `f` and then set u to `"\n + u"` accordingly:

```
func (g *Graph) Walk(u string, f bool) {
    for _, v := range g.Edges[u] {
        if f {
            u = "\n" + u
        } else {
            u = ""
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s -> %s", u, v)
        g.Walk(v, false)
    }
}
```